# start script not working with npm start, but works fine with node server.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I have been stuck on an issue for quite some time and cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. When I cd into my project's src folder and run node server.js everything works as expected. I am able to open the application on localhost with http://localhost:3000/client/pantry/index.html. However, when trying to make a start script in package.json I encounter some issues. My script does indeed connect to the server as I get a message in console "Server listening on port 3000" from this bit of code: `app.listen(port, () => { console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`); });`  , but when I go to http://localhost:3000/client/pantry/index.html I receive a 404 (Not found) response and page does not load.
**Here is a list of things that I have already tried:**

1. delete node modules folder and run npm install
2. `  "scripts": {

"start": "node src/server.js"

}`

this also includes almost every combination of folder structure I can think of
(i.e: "start": "node ./src/server.js", "start": "node ../src/server.js", "start": "node ./../server.js", "start": "node server.js", relative path, full path, etc.)

3. run script from src directory with BOTH npm start and npm run start
4. run script from project directory ("MyPantry") with BOTH npm start and npm run start
5. reinstalling node

**What I think the issue could possibly be:**

1. Something wrong with folder structure
2. Some middleware issue that only applies with start script.  I am using `app.use("/client", express.static("client"));`, within my server.js file that allows access to client folder on web. (once again, works fine with node server.js without start script).
   **Below are pictures of folder/file structure along with 404 error, package.json, and web view with/without start script:**

[image: folder structure and 404 error]

[image: package.json file]

[image: web view with start script]

without start script vvv
[image: web view running node server.js in terminal]

[full packag.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IcGW.png)
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure you are running `node src/server.js` from exactly the same directory as `npm run start`? It should be the directory where package.json is.

Comment: show your require/import statements?

Comment: @Kokodoko I suppose this is another issue im having. If I cd into src and run node server.js it works, but if I try running node src/server.js from project directory it does not and I have no idea why. Shouldn't it be able to find server.js from within src? And to answer your question I have tried running the start script from both directories with no luck

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial my imports for my server.js file are simply just express and morgan. import express from "express";
import morgan from "morgan";

Comment: i meant your "client" path, are you happen to be running some kind of alias mods?

Comment: @SomeoneSpecial oh sorry. No I am not using anything like that.

Comment: Would be nice if you show the statements as well as full package.json, in case there are errors which we can spot. Hard to spot errors if you just provide random screenshots and codes. Currently, cannot spot anything that's suspicious

Comment: I have provided a picture of the full package.json on the bottom of post. I believe that this is the only other thing of use that may narrow down the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem. It was indeed the middleware used to serve the client file on the web. I had to change `app.use("/client", express.static("client"));` to `app.use("/client", express.static("./src/client"));`. Now npm start works and node src/server.js works.